# DNI (Spanish national ID) Calculator

Tags: python

A DNI (Spain's National Identification Document) is formed by 8 digits and a letter, and they are related to one another as follows:

```py
number % 23 -> letter_index
```

Where the sequence of letters to be indexed is `TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET`

The following program allows calculating the letter given the number, finding some missing numbers, and finding all possible DNIs given some of the numbers and the letter:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional, List


@dataclass
class Dni:

    LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY = 8
    LENGTH = LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY + 1

    number: Optional[int] = None
    letter: Optional[str] = None
    missing_digits: List[int] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])

    def get_number_as_str(self) -> str:
        '''Return the number representing unknown digits as "?"

        For example, if number=11_011_111 and missing_digits=[2],
        returned value is "11?11111"
        '''
        number = self.number if self.number is not None else 0
        number_as_str = str(number).zfill(Dni.LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY)

        # number is converted to list so that missing digits can be replaced
        number_as_list = list(number_as_str)
        if self.missing_digits:
            for missing_digit in self.missing_digits:
                number_as_list[missing_digit] = '?'

        return ''.join(number_as_list)

    def get_letter_as_str(self) -> str:
        '''Return the letter or "?" if lettter is not known'''
        return self.letter.upper() if self.letter else '?'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_number_as_str() + self.get_letter_as_str()

    @classmethod
    def from_dni(clss, dni):
        return Dni(dni.number, dni.letter, [i for i in dni.missing_digits])
```

```py
from typing import Iterable, Generator, Optional
import itertools

from dni_calculator import Dni


class DniCalculator:

    _LETTERS = 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET'

    def find_letter(self, dni: Dni) -> Optional[Dni]:
        '''Find the letter corresponding to the given dni

        Example:
            find_letter(Dni(11111111)) -> 11111111H

        Args:
            dni: The dni whose letter is to be found.
                All of its digits have to be present
        '''
        if dni.missing_digits and len(dni.missing_digits) != 0:
            print(f'Invalid dni given: "{dni}". '
                + 'There cannot be missing numbers when finding a letter')
            return None
        if dni.letter is not None:
            if self._check_valid(dni):
                print(f'The given dni is already complete and valid: "{dni}"')
                return Dni.from_dni(dni)
            else:
                print(f'Letter provided. Wont look for it "{dni}"')
                return None
        res_dni = Dni.from_dni(dni)
        res_dni.letter = self._get_letter(dni.number)
        return res_dni

    def _get_letter(self, dni_number: int) -> str:
        '''Return the letter corresponding to the given dni_number'''
        return self._LETTERS[dni_number % 23]

    def _check_valid(self, dni: Dni) -> bool:
        '''Check whether the given dni is valid

        Args:
            dni: A Dni with all digits and letter present
                Example: Dni(11_111_111, 'H')
        '''
        return self._get_letter(dni.number) == dni.letter

    def find_missing_num(self, dni: Dni) -> Optional[Dni]:
        '''Find the first complete dni valid for the given dni

        Args:
            dni: The dni for which to find the missing numbers

                It should have at least one missing digit.
                It also has to contain the letter.

                Examples:
                    Dni(11_111_011, 'H', [5])
                    Dni(11_100_111, 'H', [3, 4])
        '''
        return next(self.find_all_possible_dnis(dni), None)

    def find_all_possible_dnis(self, dni: Dni) -> Generator[Dni, None, None]:
        '''Find the all of the valid dnis for the given dni

        Args:
            dni: The dni for which to find the missing numbers

                It should have at least one missing digit.
                It also has to contain the letter.

                Examples:
                    Dni(11_111_011, 'H', [5])
                    Dni(11_100_111, 'H', [3, 4])
        '''
        if dni.letter is None:
            print(f'Cannot fing missing numbers if no letter is given: "{dni}"')
            return None

        num_missing_digits = len(dni.missing_digits)
        if num_missing_digits == 0:
            if self._check_valid(dni):
                print(f'The given dni is already complete and valid: "{dni}"')
                yield Dni.from_dni(dni)
                return None
            else:
                print(f'All digits provided. Unable to find missing ones "{dni}"')
                return None

        res_dni = Dni.from_dni(dni)
        missing_digits = res_dni.missing_digits
        res_dni.missing_digits = []
        prev_digits_to_check = 0
        for digits_to_check in self._get_generator_for_digits(missing_digits):
            res_dni.number -= prev_digits_to_check
            res_dni.number += digits_to_check
            prev_digits_to_check = digits_to_check
            if self._check_valid(res_dni):
                yield Dni.from_dni(res_dni)

    def _get_generator_for_digit(self, digit_pos: int) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
        '''Return the different value the digit at position digit_pos can have

        Examples:
            digit_pos=7 -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9
            digit_pos=6 -> 0, 10, 20, ..., 80, 90
            digit_pos=0 -> 0, 10_000_000, ..., 90_000_000

        Args:
            digit_pos: A number from 0 to 9
        '''
        power = Dni.LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY - digit_pos
        for number in range(0, 10 ** power, 10 ** (power-1)):
            yield number

    def _get_generator_for_digits(self, digits_pos: Iterable[int]) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
        '''Returns all combinations of values the digits at position digits_pos can have

        Examples:
            digit_pos=(7,) -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9
            digit_pos=(6,) -> 0, 10, 20, ..., 80, 90
            digit_pos=(0,) -> 0, 10_000_000, ..., 90_000_000
            digit_pos=(6, 7) -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 98, 99
            digit_pos=(5, 7) -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 9, 100, 101, ... 109, 200, ..., 908, 909
            digit_pos=(0, 5) -> 0, 10_000_000, 10_000_100, 10_000_200, ..., 90_000_900

        Args:
            digits_pos: An iterable whose values have to be between 0 and 9
                For the output to be in an expectable order, the iterable
                has to return the numbers in increasing order.

                For example, if digits_pos=(7, 6), the yielded values will be:
                0, 10, 20, 30, ... 90, 1, 11, 21, ...
        '''
        digits_generators = [self._get_generator_for_digit(digit_pos)
                             for digit_pos in digits_pos]
        digits_generator = itertools.product(*digits_generators)
        # return digits_generator
        return map(sum, digits_generator)
```

And here are some tests:

```py
from dni_calculator import Dni, DniCalculator

dni_calc = DniCalculator()

assert dni_calc.find_letter(Dni(11_111_111)) == Dni(11_111_111, 'H')
assert dni_calc.find_letter(Dni(71_091_510)) == Dni(71_091_510, 'M')
assert dni_calc.find_letter(Dni(82_416_679)) == Dni(82_416_679, 'C')

assert dni_calc.find_missing_num(Dni(11_111_011, 'H', missing_digits=[5])) == Dni(11_111_111, 'H')
assert dni_calc.find_missing_num(Dni(75_623_008, 'E', missing_digits=[5])) == Dni(75_623_608, 'E')
assert dni_calc.find_missing_num(Dni(20_602_203, 'M', missing_digits=[3, 6])) == Dni(20_612_283, 'M')

dnis_generator = dni_calc.find_all_possible_dnis(Dni(5240700, 'Q', missing_digits=[6, 7]))
expected_results = (
    Dni(5240704, 'Q'),
    Dni(5240727, 'Q'),
    Dni(5240750, 'Q'),
    Dni(5240773, 'Q'),
    Dni(5240796, 'Q'),
 )
for dni, expected_result in zip(dnis_generator, expected_results):
    assert dni == expected_result
```

The full code providing a simple CLI interface using [fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire) can be found at [m-alorda/dni_calculator](https://github.com/m-alorda/dni_calculator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Basics

[PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) asks for double quotes and not single quotes for docstrings.

These:

```
LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY = 8
LENGTH = LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY + 1
```

should be type-hinted as `ClassVar[int]`.

By convention the class reference variable for class methods is `cls`, not `clss`.

`from_dni` does not actually refer to `cls`, but it should: rather than constructing via `Dni`, you should construct `cls`. Beyond that, though, I'd sooner expect this to be an instance method `copy` that returns a copy of `self`.

Ideally `Dni` should be made immutable by passing `frozen=true` to its decorator. This will reveal some design warts: currently `DniCalculator` is responsible for mutating `Dni.missing_digits`, but it should not be.

`_get_generator_for_digit` may be static, or better yet a class method on `Dni` itself.

This:

```
print(f'Invalid dni given: "{self}". '
      + 'There cannot be missing numbers when finding a letter')
```

doesn't need the `+` and can use implicit concatenation.

`find_letter` should `raise` instead of `print`. Printing can be done at the outer level.

Typo: `lettter` -> `letter`

`[i for i in dni.missing_digits]` can just be `list(dni.missing_digits)`.

`_check_valid` would be more natural as a `@property is_valid` on `Dni` itself.

This test:

```
for dni, expected_result in zip(dnis_generator, expected_results):
```

hides a failure mode where there is a length mismatch. Using `zip_longest` will fix this.

### Congruential acceleration

Recognize that a problem such as finding all numbers for

```
052407??Q
```

is really a [congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence) of the form

$$
5,240,700 + 10x + y \equiv 16 \mod 23
$$

You should be able to apply equivalence relation identities such that you find all answers analytically rather than by brute force; for your example:

$$ y \equiv 16 - 5,240,700  \mod 23 $$
$$ y \equiv 4  \mod 23 $$
$$ y = 4 + 23 n, 0 \le n \le 4 $$

I've not shown this in the implementation below.

### Suggested

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Iterable, Optional, ClassVar, Tuple, Sequence
import itertools


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Dni:
    LETTERS: ClassVar[str] = 'TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE'
    LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY: ClassVar[int] = 8
    LENGTH: ClassVar[int] = LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY + 1

    digits: Tuple[Optional[int], ...]
    letter: Optional[str] = None

    @classmethod
    def from_number(cls, x: int, letter: Optional[str] = None) -> 'Dni':
        if x >= 10**cls.LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY:
            raise ValueError(f'{x} has incorrect length')
        return cls(
            digits=tuple(int(c) for c in str(x)),
            letter=letter,
        )

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, s: str) -> 'Dni':
        *digits, letter = s
        if len(digits) != cls.LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY:
            raise ValueError(f'{s} has incorrect length')

        return cls(
            digits=tuple(
                None if d == '?' else int(d) for d in digits
            ),
            letter=None if letter == '?' else letter,
        )

    @property
    def is_complete(self) -> bool:
        return (
            self.letter is not None and
            not any(d is None for d in self.digits)
        )

    @property
    def number(self) -> int:
        x = 0
        for digit in self.digits:
            if digit is None:
                raise ValueError('Partial number cannot be linearised')
            x = 10*x + digit
        return x

    @property
    def number_as_str(self) -> str:
        """Return the number representing unknown digits as "?"

        For example, if number=11_011_111 and missing_digits=[2],
        returned value is "11?11111"
        """

        number_as_list = []
        for d in self.digits:
            number_as_list += '?' if d is None else str(d)

        return ''.join(number_as_list)

    @property
    def letter_as_str(self) -> str:
        """Return the letter or "?" if letter is not known"""
        if self.letter is None:
            return '?'
        return self.letter

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.number_as_str + self.letter_as_str

    def copy(self) -> 'Dni':
        return Dni(self.digits)

    @classmethod
    def _get_letter(cls, number: int) -> str:
        return cls.LETTERS[number % len(cls.LETTERS)]

    @property
    def expected_letter(self) -> str:
        """Find the letter corresponding to the given dni

        Example:
            expected_letter(Dni(11111111)) -> 11111111H

        Args:
            dni: The dni whose letter is to be found.
                All of its digits have to be present
        """
        return self._get_letter(self.number)

    @classmethod
    def _get_generator_for_digit(cls, digit_pos: int) -> Sequence[int]:
        """Return the different value the digit at position digit_pos can have

        Examples:
            digit_pos=7 -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9
            digit_pos=6 -> 0, 10, 20, ..., 80, 90
            digit_pos=0 -> 0, 10_000_000, ..., 90_000_000

        Args:
            digit_pos: A number from 0 to 9
        """
        power = cls.LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY - digit_pos
        return range(0, 10**power, 10**(power - 1))

    @classmethod
    def _get_generator_for_digits(cls, digits_pos: Iterable[int]) -> Iterable[int]:
        """Returns all combinations of values the digits at position digits_pos can have

        Examples:
            digit_pos=(7,) -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 8, 9
            digit_pos=(6,) -> 0, 10, 20, ..., 80, 90
            digit_pos=(0,) -> 0, 10_000_000, ..., 90_000_000
            digit_pos=(6, 7) -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 98, 99
            digit_pos=(5, 7) -> 0, 1, 2, ..., 9, 100, 101, ... 109, 200, ..., 908, 909
            digit_pos=(0, 5) -> 0, 10_000_000, 10_000_100, 10_000_200, ..., 90_000_900

        Args:
            digits_pos: An iterable whose values have to be between 0 and 9
                For the output to be in an expectable order, the iterable
                has to return the numbers in increasing order.

                For example, if digits_pos=(7, 6), the yielded values will be:
                0, 10, 20, 30, ... 90, 1, 11, 21, ...
        """
        digits_generators = (cls._get_generator_for_digit(digit_pos)
                             for digit_pos in digits_pos)
        digits_generator = itertools.product(*digits_generators)
        return map(sum, digits_generator)

    @property
    def missing_num(self) -> Optional['Dni']:
        """Find the first complete dni valid for the given dni

        Args:
            dni: The dni for which to find the missing numbers

                It should have at least one missing digit.
                It also has to contain the letter.

                Examples:
                    Dni(11_111_011, 'H', [5])
                    Dni(11_100_111, 'H', [3, 4])
        """
        return next(self.all_possible_dnis, None)

    @property
    def all_possible_dnis(self) -> Iterable['Dni']:
        """Find the all of the valid dnis for the given dni

        Args:
            dni: The dni for which to find the missing numbers

                It should have at least one missing digit.
                It also has to contain the letter.

                Examples:
                    Dni(11_111_011, 'H', [5])
                    Dni(11_100_111, 'H', [3, 4])
        """

        base = sum(
            0 if d is None else d * 10**(self.LENGTH_NUMS_ONLY - i)
            for i, d in enumerate(self.digits, 1)
        )

        digits_pos = [i for i, d in enumerate(self.digits) if d is None]
        for addend in self._get_generator_for_digits(digits_pos):
            number = addend + base
            letter = self._get_letter(number)
            if self.letter is None or letter == self.letter:
                yield Dni.from_number(number, letter)


def test():
    assert Dni.from_number(11_111_111).expected_letter == 'H'
    assert Dni.from_number(71_091_510).expected_letter == 'M'
    assert Dni.from_number(82_416_679).expected_letter == 'C'

    dni = Dni.parse('11111?11H').missing_num
    assert dni.letter == 'H'
    assert dni.number == 11_111_111

    dni = Dni.parse('75623?08E').missing_num
    assert dni.letter == 'E'
    assert dni.number == 75_623_608

    dni = Dni.parse('206?22?3M').missing_num
    assert dni.letter == 'M'
    assert dni.number == 20_612_283

    dnis_generator = Dni.parse('052407??Q').all_possible_dnis
    expected_numbers = (
        5240704,
        5240727,
        5240750,
        5240773,
        5240796,
    )
    for dni, expected_number in itertools.zip_longest(dnis_generator, expected_numbers):
        assert dni.number == expected_number
        assert dni.letter == 'Q'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all of this helpful feedback. I also knew there had to be a better way to find all possible dnis, but I did not know about congruence relations. Lastly, there is something I'm not sure of: Why do you think using property is better than methods? For simple things like `number`, `number_as_str` or even `expected_letter`, I can understand. But for some others, like `all_possible_dnis` I feel like properties hide the fact that some actual (even expensive) calculation is being done (`Dni.parse('????????H').all_possible_dnis`)

Comment: If you're worried about property computation expense, apply an LRU cache. `@property` is just syntax sugar and is more convenient to invoke than the equivalent function notation.

Comment: I agree with @m-alorda - when creating objects, `.methods()` are actions the class undertakes on itself, and `.properties` are characteristics of the object. Conventions help to faciliate communicate between developers.